# CSS: How to obtain Width of an arbitrary sized <li> Element?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

Assumed we have this simple horizontal navigation bar:

```css
* { list-style-type: none; }

ul { display: flex }

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<container>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Test 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Test 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</container>
```

---

Is there an option available to identify the width of each `<li>` element and store it as a variable? I would desire something like the following approach to store the width for further usage.

```
:root {
   --identify-width-of-li:nth-child(1);

.red_circle {
   display: block;
   width: var(--width-of-li:nth-child(1));
   height: 10px;
}
```

Unfortunately, the size of each element increases/decreases depending on the amount of text chars.

Comment: not without JavaScript, but can you tell what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You cannot do it in css, you need to use javascript for this. What are you trying to achieve exactly? Maybe css can do it without knowing the width

Comment: @zdolny and @Huangism: Thanks for your comments! My goal is to position a nice slider below the navigation bar that should ```translateX``` to the ```<li>``` element that is currently hovered and auto-adopt to its specific width. Something like this, but WITHOUT the need to specify each width of the ```<li>``` elements by myself... https://codepen.io/mnafricano/pen/jcrzm